# ngx-admin side-bar menu grouping/clustering options

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

does anyone know if ngx-admin support some kind of sub-menu options clustering, ie, introduction of a delimiter (a simple horizontal separator) or group/cluster with titles?

Many thanks.
Pedro

[mock-up example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV9zU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  {
    title: 'Reporting',
    icon: 'lock-outline',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Group Title A',
        icon: 'lock-outline',
        group: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'Menu Item 1',
        link: '/auth/register',
      },
      {
        title: 'Menu Item 2',
        link: '/auth/request-password',
      },
      {
        title: 'Menu Item 3',
        link: '/auth/request-password',
      },
    ],
  },
```

you can make a group title by adding `group:true`